# Claims problem when opening documents

Tags: document-library, claims

following this tutorial (http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx) I configured the claims for my web app... but something is wrong because i get a error page whenever i click a document in a library (liek to view or edit it)... here is the error screenshot [image: Error SP]

everything else is working just ok... this "feature" (people open files and alter without having to download and reupload later) is very critical for my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state in the picture that the site collection at '/' doesn't even exitst.

It should otherwise you're running unsupported unless every site collection is a host header site collection in the web application. See [SharePoint 2010: Supportability of unprovisioned root site in a SharePoint web application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2590564)

Comment: TKS! that solved it!!! YOU, MY FRIEND, ARE A GENIUS!!!